# Storing css values in database table

Tags: html, mysql, css

I have planned to build a database table for storing css values of a form. The forms are dynamic, It means that one cannot say what kind of elements that it contain in composition.

For example, the form may contain a composition of text input boxes, radio buttons, drop down boxes. Here is my question: If I need to store css values for this kind of form, How can I build my table.(css property and its value will also be assigned on form generation itself)

As far as I have planned the tables may go like this:

Consider two tables: `classes, Styles`

Classes table has columns like: `id, class_name`

Styles table has columns like: `id, class_id(foreign key), css_property, css_values`

If I assign class for each of the form elements, then I can use the above tables for storing css values. But is this the straight way for solving problems like this? If not, is there any better solution than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't store CSS values in the database. You are just creating more work for yourself and slowing down the process. What you should do instead is add classes to your form fields and just write styles in an [external stylesheet](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) that correspond to each class.

Comment: But Css values will also be assigned in dynamic. I mean, the form should be generated along with css. It should be retrieved along with css. In such cases we cannot go without storing css values in database

Comment: simply store stylesheet name in database rather than styles.

Comment: Why do you need to generate CSS on the fly?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're building a form editor that allows users to assign styles to form elements, and you want to be able to save these changes in a database. If that's the case, you probably already have a table like `form_elements` and a table like `forms`--I'd just add two text columns: `form_elements.extra_html_attrs` and `forms.extra_html`. This would allow you to attach arbitrary attributes to each element (e.g. extra_html_attrs=`class="fancy-element" style="width:100px"`) and include arbitrary html in the form (e.g. extra_html=`<style>.fancy-element{border:blue}</style>`). Modeling CSS-related attributes in separate database tables adds complexity and doesn't buy you anything in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Times have changed.

CSS-in-JS solutions format CSS as JSON, and thus can be stored in a database fairly easily. While I would not go so far as to store complete style definitions in a DB, I think it does make sense to store design tokens this way. Then, token values can be edited via a CMS, eliminating the need for engineering to execute simple changes to the design system.

Alternatively, design token values can be exported directly from Figma so that changes to an application theme are reflected immediately after each build without further developer intervention.

This may be over-engineered for single small applications, but if you are designing frontend architecture to support multiple applications using a single shared component library, this could be a good solution.

Check out the [Styled Components API](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming), the [Design Tokens Plugin](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/888356646278934516/Design-Tokens) for Figma, and [Amazon Style Dictionary](https://amzn.github.io/style-dictionary/#/).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can generate the form fields dynamically and asign Field Id's and unique Form Id, if you want to asign css styles like a position, colors, sizes etc, you would asign all of these properties and values to each field like #FormId #FieldID {properties:values;} and store  in database in a unique text field.

Form's Table

```
FormId  | Html | Styles | "the rest of the interested form properties"
```

:)

Comment: Yes.I think this is what I have planned as of now. Does your solution differ than my own suggestion as I explained in question? Sorry, I could not get your answer clearly

Answer (score 1):

I would create a javascript-class and use JQuery. The each of queries would et the correct class using addClass. The class you are adding would be created dynamicly in the javascript-class.

Comment: I actually needed to store those CSS values in table. It's bcoz the css values for each property changes dynamically by the user.

Comment: When loaded first time, you pass the css-values togeather with the html. Then you will need an ajax call to the server to store the actual css-class names if the user changes them.

Answer (score 1):

I had same task to store css from file to database.

You need to read file and then merge `bin2hex` and `UNHEX` to get it done.

Here is the final solution

```
function dalm_20230801194000()
{
    $cssFilePath = dirname(__DIR__).'/assets/02/css/styles.css';
    $cssContent = file_get_contents($cssFilePath);
    $hexRepresentation = bin2hex($cssContent);
    $theme_stub = 'default';
    DB::query(null, "update `engine_site_themes` set `styles` = UNHEX('{$hexRepresentation}') where `engine_site_themes`.`stub` = '{$theme_stub}'")->execute();
}

dalm_20230801194000();
```